# Can the subdomain URL segment be used as a class in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain, segments

I need to use a subdomain as a class. ie, instead of:

www.example.com/class/function/ID eg www.example.com/town-name/history/1

I need

class.example.com/function/ID eg town-name.example.com/history/1

I've wildcarded the subdomain in nginx, now I've googled and read

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

but nothing relevant. I need it to be so that if another town is added to the db, it'll resolve that new town and its details.

I see many discussions about rewrites, redirects etc, but I specifically need to use the subdomain town name as the class variable. If possible, in an idea world, I could use both together, but I doubt that's possible?

I've had it going fine in plain old php for a couple of years now; now I want to upgrade to codeigniter without ruining my old structure if possible (plus there's a good reason for it).

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it. I'm doing it for one of my projects.

In the constructor of your controller, just [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the current url and get the subdomain and pass it in your method as a variable

```
public class Controller extends CI_Controller {

    $subdomain = null;

    public __construct() 
    {
        // explode url here and set $this->subdomain = the actual subdomain
    }

    public function index() 
    {
        if($this->subdomain == null) {
            show_404();
        } else {
            // do what you wish
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Catfish for the extremely fast response! In fact, I'm using CI_starter, so I ended up with something slightly different, editing /ci_starter/application/core/MY_controller.php. The result is at http://pastebin.com/SsUWME4t - it _seems_ to work, but please let me know if I've gone horribly wrong and commited a cardinal codeigniter sin!

Comment: Looks pretty good. I'm not familiar with CI_Starter (what is that?) and i'm not familiar with the layout class you are using. Other than that it looks like what I have done.

Comment: CI_starter is just CI with a few things insalled, like sparks, and http://getsparks.org/ was where I first saw it https://github.com/linuxjuggler/CI_Starter, and the layout is part of that. If the layout class works the way I think it does (and am using it!) it allows me to try and switch between 2 or 3 different layouts "on the fly". Anyway, you've solved my problem! Thank you very much.